# ValueError is thrown when trying to iterate through dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove Outliers from my data by IQR method. But when I try to iterate through the columns of dataframe using `.loc`, I get

> ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Here is my code,

```
for col in df.columns:
    q3 = df[col].quantile(0.75)
    q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    ll = q1 - 1.5* iqr
    ul = q3 + 1.5* iqr
    df1 = df.loc[(df[col]>ll) & (df[col] < ul)] #Value Error
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help?

Comment: Actually this code is working for small dataframe, but for large dataframe, this error is thrown. Dataframe which I have used is = http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/airq402.dat